# How to use nginx to redirect based on value of variable in requested location?

Tags: nginx, redirect

I am new to nginx from apache, and I'm trying to do a redirection that follows this simple format.

http://sub.domain.tld/location=BLAH

should redirect to

http://sub.domain.tld/location/directory1/directory2/BLAH/index.html

The sub.domain.tld is http and https enabled---not sure if that makes a difference or not.

Current server configuration:

```
server {
    server_name sub.domain.tld;
    listen 1.2.3.4:80;
    listen [dead:beef:feed:deed::]:80;
    root /path/to/web/root/;

    if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$ ) { return 444; }

    location / {
            index will.never.exist.xyz;
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            autoindex on;
            autoindex_exact_size off;
            autoindex_format html;
            autoindex_localtime off;
    }

    listen [dead:beef:feed:deed::]:443 ssl;
    listen 1.2.3.4:443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /path/.../fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/.../privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Server Fault! Can you please [edit](https://serverfault.com/posts/949452/edit) your question and post your current `nginx` configuration? Feel free to "anonymize" it.

Comment: Is the URI `/location=BLAH` or did you mean `/?location=BLAH`?

Comment: Hi Richard, the URI is /location=BLAH (ie: not done through PHP, or other server side parsed scripting). It has to be an nginx redirect and follow that syntax.